# How do I properly organize and implement SFML audio in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, audio, sfml

For one of my high school independent study projects, I have to make a simple game (specifically the game "Snake") using the SFML in Visual C++ (yes I am new to C++ and SFML). I have coded the core and graphics of the game and now I am working on the audio and sound effects. I have read some of the things about audio in the SFML book, but was still confused on how to properly implement this into my code. I know that I have to make a sf:Sound and an sf::SoundBuffer object, load using loadFromFile and openFromFile for sound and music respectively, and  use sound.play() and sound.stop() to play and stop respectively. However, this is where the question comes in. Do I load these objects in the main method, do I make them as global objects so I can use throughout the code, do I load in the function where the sfx takes place, do I make an object containing all the sound?...Generally, how do I properly organize and implement these audio files within my code. Here is what I have so far:

***Main Method***

```
/*Main method*///
int main(){
    /*Initialize the objects*/
    Snake snake = Snake();
    sf::Text textCount;
    Apple apple(0, 0);
    apple.locateApple();
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight), "SFML Application" );
    /*Load the audio*/

    sf::Music backgroundMusic;
    sf::Sound eating;
    sf::SoundBuffer sb_eating;
    sf::Sound moving;
    sf::SoundBuffer sb_moving;
    sf::Sound losing;
    sf::SoundBuffer sb_losing;
    sf::Sound begin;
    sf::SoundBuffer sb_begin;

    if (!backgroundMusic.openFromFile("backgroundmusic.wav"))
        std::cerr << "Error opening \"backgroundmusic.wav\"" << std::endl;
    if (!sb_eating.loadFromFile("eatingsfx.wav"))
        std::cerr << "Error opening \"eatingsfx.wav\"" << std::endl;
    if (!sb_moving.loadFromFile("movingsfx.wav"))
        std::cerr << "Error opening \"movingsfx.wav\"" << std::endl;
    if (!sb_losing.loadFromFile("losingsfx.wav"))
        std::cerr << "Error opening \"losingsfx.wav\"" << std::endl;
    if (!sb_begin.loadFromFile("beginsfx.wav"))
        std::cerr << "Error opening \"beginsfx.wav\"" << std::endl;

    eating.setBuffer(sb_eating);
    moving.setBuffer(sb_moving);
    losing.setBuffer(sb_losing);
    begin.setBuffer(sb_begin);

    moving.setVolume(50);

    backgroundMusic.setLoop(true);
    backgroundMusic.play();

    /*Load the font*/
    sf::Font font;
    if (!(font.loadFromFile("arial.ttf")))
        std::cout << "Error loading fonts" << std::endl;
    /*Create the text*/
    textCount.setFont(font);
    textCount.setString(std::string("points: ") + std::to_string(points));
    textCount.setColor(sf::Color::Red);
    textCount.setCharacterSize(20);
    textCount.setPosition(windowWidth / 2 - (textCount.getString().getSize()*(textCount.getCharacterSize() / 5)), textCount.getCharacterSize() - 5);
    textCount.setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);

    window.draw(textCount);

    /*Set Framerate fps*/
    window.setFramerateLimit(15);

    /*MAIN GAME LOOP*/
    counterTick = 1;


    while (inGame)
    {
        std::string counter = std::to_string(counterTick);
        std::cout << "Tick: " + counter << std::endl;

        window.clear(sf::Color::Black);
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::Escape)) break;
        /*Call Updates*/
        snake.input();
        snake.checkReals();
        snake.moveUpdate();
        moving.play();

        /*Call Collisions*/
        std::cout << "     Outside Collision Loop " << std::endl;
        checkApple(snake, apple);
        checkBoundary(snake);

        /*Call Draw*/
        std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> shapearray = snake.draw();
        for (int i = shapearray.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            window.draw(shapearray[i]);
        }
        window.draw(textCount);
        window.draw(apple.draw());
        window.display();

        counterTick++;

    }
    losing.play();
    backgroundMusic.stop();
    std::system("PAUSE");//bad practice, debuggin purposes
    return 0;
}
```

For example, how would I be able to play the "eating" sfx when the snake collides with the apple? Here is my checkApple() method:

***Check Apple Method***

```
void checkApple(Snake mA, Apple& mB){
    if ((mA.x[0] == mB.x()) && (mA.y[0] == mB.y())){
        dots += dotInterval;
        std::cout << "In Collision Method" << std::endl;
        points++;
        textCount.setString(std::string("points: ") + std::to_string(dots - 3));
        mB.locateApple();

    }
}
```

I am new to these forums as well so if there are any questions please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off all, I'm fairly new to C++ & SFML. I'm sure there's a better solution to your problem than the one I've got, but here goes.

I have a method called loadAudio(std::string source) and a vector where I store the audio.

```
class Audio {

private:
    sf::SoundBuffer buffer;
    sf::Sound sound;
    std::string _src;
public:
    void init(std::string src) {        //Initialize audio
        _src = src;
        buffer.loadFromFile(src);
        sound.setBuffer(buffer);
    }
    void play(){
        sound.play();       // Play queued audio
    }
    void stop(){
        sound.stop();
    }
    //void setVolume(), void setPitch() ....


};

std::vector<Audio*> audio;

void loadAudio(std::vector<std::string> src) {
    audio.push_back(new Audio());
    audio.back()->init(src[i]);
}
```

So basically at the beginning of the game I declare the sounds like this:

```
loadAudio("sound/foo.wav");
loadAudio("sound/bar.wav");
```

I can then access the sounds stored in the vector using `audio[0]->play()`

Comment: Very simple yet efficient code. A very helpful member gave me another good way to work with audio in my other question. Good luck with learning SFML as I am new too. Thanks